# multiple python scripts accessing neo4j database

Tags: python, neo4j, py2neo, bolt, neo4j-driver

I'm using a Neo4j database (local community server) with my own graph and I'm doing some link prediction via python scripts. The graph is quite large so I outsourced the computing to a HPC Cluster. My Problem now is: on the cluster I'd like to run multiple python scripts in parallel which all access the db via bolt:///localhost:7474/.

The problem is: after the first script has started the database is locked, so the other scripts break. I tried copying the database on the cluster and running it multiple times. However, since it is a local instance, it still causes problems because you cannot access two databases via one port (bolt:///localhost:7474/). Any ideas how to fix this? Is there a way? I'm not too familiar with Neo4j and I'm really not familiar to Linux and the HPC Cluster. So any ideas would be very much of help!

Is the neo4j driver instead of py2neo a solution? But it also uses the bolt connection, so I doubt it.

Cheers!